# How to prevent symfony to read Request body to be able to process it like an input stream

Tags: php, symfony

Using Symfony 6, I want to process the HTTP Request body as a pure input stream by reading `php://input'`. Something like this:

```php
$bodyStream = fopen('php://input', 'r');
$bufLength = 10000;
while($buf = stream_get_contents($bodyStream, $bufLength)) {
   /* Do something with buffer data */
}
```

As data incoming is of variable size and could be potentially big, this way there is no memory hit.

It works great in pure PHP, but inside a Symfony controller it triggers an allowed memory size error:

```
NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 48234528 bytes) in /usr/share/nginx/html/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Request.php on line 1503
```

Controller code example:

```php
#[Route('/my-endpoint', name: 'my.endpoint', methods: 'PUT')]
public function action(): Response

    $bodyStream = fopen('php://input', 'r');
    $bufLength = 10000;
    while($buf = stream_get_contents($bodyStream, $bufLength)) {
       /* Do something with buffer data */
    }

    return new Response("hello");
}
```

The allowed memory size error cleary demonstrates that the Symfony HttpFoundation component reads and stores somewhere the entire request body before giving control to the controller action. (`Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::getContent()` is called somewhere).

Is there a way to prevent Symfony to read the request body ?

Answer (score 0):

So after some xdebug stracktracing the "culprit" is the development web profiler. Disabling it removes the memory size limit error.

The profiler can be programatically disabled for specific action as explained in documentation [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/profiler.html#enabling-the-profiler-conditionally)